# What to do with an unused repository clone

Tags: mercurial

This is mainly a Mercurial based question. Specifically Eclipse Mercurial.

After cloning the central repo, making the changes (branch, new feature, merge...), the clone on the desktop is idle and not necessary (it won't be used again, probably). What should be done with it? Right click, delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the changes have been pushed back to the central repo and you won’t be using it again anytime soon, then yes there is no reason to keep it around.

Comment: Yeah, but is there a "graceful" way to get rid of it? Is it just a matter of delete, like any ordinary file?

Comment: Yup, after all the repository is nothing more than a directory and file structure in the .hg folder.